# Как подключить стили в php файле

Tags: php, html, css, wamp

[image: дерево файлов]

Не могу корректно прописать путь к CSS файлу. Прогуглил уже все, что только можно.
в .htaccess код:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %(REQUST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUST_FILENAME) !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `/test/` то не хотите свой написать в начало, раз используете его как `RewriteBase`?

Comment: @teran, добавлял и `test/` и `/test/` и `./test/` и `../test/` все равно не работает

Comment: не надо пробовать добавлять все что угодно, и про всякие точки в путях вообще забудьте. В целом не надо весь код проекта хранить в корне сайта. В корне должен быть индекс пхп, стили, js и картинки. Весь пхп код  и шаблоны должны быт недоступны извне. Что касается стилей, то введите урл файла стилей в строке браузера и смотрите что получаете в ответ.

Comment: 99.9% ТС пытается взять то, что недоступно извне

Comment: @teran не открывается файл, если я прописываю к нему путь http://localhost/test/temlate/css/style.css